# Counting a list of compared criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've got a list of distances from an external supplier, and I'd like to check their accuracy. I have their distances in column `N`, with distances from our verified distance tables in column `Q`. As a minor complication, not all cells in `Q` are populated.

[image: Distance columns]

Rows highlighted in green indicate identical distances; light red backgrounds indicate minor errors (errors outside a 10% margin are marked in bright orange, not shown here), with blue text for lower-than-real and red for higher-than-real.

I'd like to show (in cell `AW1`, not that it matters) an accuracy percentage by taking the total number of cells where `Nx=Qx` (per row) and dividing it by the number of cells in col `Q` that are populated. I think I should be able to do it with `COUNTIF/COUNTIFS`, but I can't seem to find the right criteria.

At the moment I'm using `COUNTIF($Q$3:$Q$3781, NOT(ISBLANK($Q3)))` to find the number of non-blank cells in `Q`, but it's not right at all. And trying `Q3=N3` as a criterion for the other side was even more unsuccessful.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Try: `=SUMPRODUCT(($N$3:$N$3781=$Q$3:$Q$3781)*1)/COUNT($Q$3:$Q$3781)`

Comment: Scott's comment has you covered.  I was just going to give you a warning on the `ISBLANK` function y ou were using.  If a cell has "" placed in it from a formula or has a space in it " ", the cell will look blank to the user.  According to Excel though the cell is not truly blank.  Depending on your needs you may want to use `<>""` or `NOT(ISBLANK(CLEAN($Q3)))` instead of what you had above.  There are limitations to CLEAN/TRIM which you can read about [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Remove-spaces-and-nonprinting-characters-from-text-023f3a08-3d56-49e4-bf0c-fe5303222c9d)

Comment: Cheers, I'll use that. I can't tell how it works - `SUMPRODUCT` is an arcane and mystical art to me - but the output looks about right. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($N$3:$N$3781=$Q$3:$Q$3781)*1)/COUNT($Q$3:$Q$3781)
```

It will count the number that match and divide by the number of cells with numbers in column Q.